Can html5QrCode use with Livewire3?
I have a button to open the modal for scanning the barcode get the result to an input and click the submit button after finishing scanning.
My JavaScript code works fine with my Laravel project. After I used livewire 3 with my project, It only opened the modal. it didn't load the camera for scanning.
please help me with this issue. below is my view and script.
enter image description here
I try to use another library like quagga but still have the same issue, I think livewire3 has to do with it.

Hi JiimyBoii, welcome to SO! Please make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post accordingly. Specifically, add your code in a code block and not as an image and try to narrow the scope down to a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
